# Put files which are compiled in yocto

Tags: yocto, compiled

I am trying to understand how to put files which are compiled at the stage of compiling in yocto.
I  blocked, and I  lost how to handle with.

Now i am interesting in compiling files named GStreamer with saved files compiled.

I want to analyze the source code step by step so that i need fils that was compiled But Yocto does not have any files like "*.[csh]"

such as

There is no c files in build/tmp/works or word-shared.

Could you please help me out?

Thank you in advance
Sincerely 
Vincent Van Park.

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific, as the question can have multiple meanings.
- Do you have files that are externally compiled, and that you want to bundle into your image?
- Do you have a recipe that compiles things, and you are working on understanding the actual process of putting those generated files into the image?

Answer (score 0):

I will interpret the question as follows:
"Where can I see the sources that were compiled, and eventually also the resulting object files?"

Generally, the sources of any package can be found at

```
build/tmp/work/$YOURTARGETARCHITECTURE/$PACKAGENAME/$VERSION/$PACKAGENAME-$VERSION
```

as well as the resulting object build tree is at

```
build/tmp/work/$YOURTARGETARCHITECTURE/$PACKAGENAME/$VERSION/build
```

Given that structure for my personal, slightly outdated build of gstreamer for an arm platform it is

```
build/tmp/work/cortexa5t2hf-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer/0.10.36-r2/gstreamer-0.10.36
```

and

```
build/tmp/work/cortexa5t2hf-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/gstreamer/0.10.36-r2/build
```

Just modify version number and architecture according to your project.